# sipml5 webrtc not able to hold a call or transfer

Tags: webrtc

Registered the users Bob , alice and hunt on local installation of kamailio server on linux redhat . The sipml5 is able to register all the three users and make calls as well as send instant message over sip .

The bad functionality of **Call transfer and call hold-resume** have worn out my energies .
So far I have tested and tried Sipml5 client with Officesip  (without webrtc2sip) , sip2sip.info  (without webrtc2sip)  , opencloud Rhino (with webrtc2sip)  and Kamalio (without webrtc2sip) , but the problem of error generation on sip reinvite persists .

Any help / hint to make **Call transfer and call hold-resume** work in sipml5 will be great.

ps: I have already posted the questions on webrtc and sipml5 google groups and issue sites however no helpful response as yet .

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the native AMI. I also had the same problems trying to make hold and transfer work but eventually I gave up, implemented them using PAMI ( Php AMI ) + Ajax
Here's the link. I hope this helps

http://marcelog.github.io/PAMI/